# How to enable strict mode in mobx store, react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how can I enable strict mode for my mobx stores in my react-native map, I use mobx stores along with react context API and hooks. After reading docs strict mode makes it so I can only change observable state in actions.

/contexts/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { ThemeStore }  from '../stores/ThemeStore.js'
import { PostStore }  from '../stores/PostStore.js'

export const storesContext = React.createContext({
  postStore: new PostStore(),
  themeStore: new ThemeStore(),
})
```

/stores/PostStore.js

```
import { observable, computed, action, flow } from "mobx";
import axios from 'axios';

export class PostStore
{
    
    
    @observable postMessage = 'Nothing to see here';
    @observable post = {};
    @observable posts = [];
    @observable pagination = {};
    @observable postCount = 0;


    @computed get visiblePosts()
    {
        return this.posts.filter( post => post.isVisible);
    };


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to enforce strict mode in your mobx stores.
The command for that would be

```
import { configure } from 'mobx';

configure({ enforceActions: "observed" })
```

That won't allow you to modify the state outside actions.
When set it sets global behaviour on the active mobx instance.

You can find more info here:
https://mobx.js.org/refguide/api.html#configure

Comment: Bu where should I use configure, I dont  have a mobx object, should I do it in hook? or in each WhateverStore?

Comment: I updated the answer. You can just import **configure** from mobx in your case. It should be global, but give it a try by setting in one store and see if it affects the other one.